# ReactJs toggle Button to open Menu

Tags: reactjs, button, ecmascript-6, toggle, eventhandler

I built a `React` component, `Toggle Menu`, which gets triggered by a button. I'm not able to see the menu open/close after the initial open. A bit lost on how to get started to fix this issue... This is the example I used for reference [How to Build a Sliding Menu Using ReactJS](https://www.codementor.io/chrisharrington/how-to-build-a-sliding-menu-using-react-js-and-less-css-du107mpij)

```
export default class ToggleMenu extends React.Component {

  showRight = () => {
    this.right.show();
  }


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.showRight = this.showRight.bind(this);
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.showRight}>Show Right Menu!</button>
        <Menu ref={right => this.right = right} alignment="right">
        <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    state = {
      visible: false,
    };

    show() {
      this.setState({ visible: true });
    }

    hide() {
      this.setState({ visible: false });
    }

    render() {
      const { visible } = this.state;

      return (
        <div className="menu">
          {
            visible &&
              <div className={this.props.alignment}>{this.props.children}</div>
          }
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By moving the State into the main ToggleMenu, you can have this component maintain the visibility of the Menu.

```
class ToggleMenu extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            visible: false  
        };

        this.toggleMenu = this.toggleMenu.bind(this);
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.setState({visible: !this.state.visible})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.toggleMenu}>Show Right Menu!</button>
                {this.state.visible && <Menu alignment="right">
                <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
                </Menu>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This allowed me to change your menu into a Stateless Component:

```
const Menu = ({alignment, children}) => (
    <div className="menu">
        <div className={alignment}>{children}</div>
    </div>
);
```

I have created a webpackbin here (now with animation): https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-Klh1VM-n4RDCkEbkK67

For transitions and animation, I recommend you look at https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group

Comment: can u maybe tell me how i can animate the menu. the problem is the menu is just rendered after on click. a simple opacity from 0.1 to 1 would be nice i tryed the whole day to manage this issue. @user2340824

Comment: No problems! I've updated my example with some transitions ;)

Comment: u are awesome i tryed yesterday the whole day to animate that stuff xD

Answer (score 3):

```
export default class ToggleMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { rightMenu: false }
    this.showRight = this.showRight.bind(this);
  }

  showRight = () => {
    this.setState({ rightMenu: !this.state.rightMenu })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.showRight}>Show Right Menu!</button>
      <Menu className={ this.state.rightMenu ? "displayBlock" : "displayNone"} ref={right => this.right = right} alignment="right">
      <MenuItem hash="first-page">First Page</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="second-page">Second Page</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem hash="third-page">Third Page</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//Style code
.displayBlock{ display: block }
.displayNone{ display: none}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    messageVisibility: true
  }  

  toggleMessage = () => {
    this.setState({
      messageVisibility: !this.state.messageVisibility
    })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>           
        <button onClick={this.toggleMessage}>Toggle Message</button>
        {this.state.messageVisibility ? <p>Toggle Content</p> : null}        
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add an eventListener to your button.

```
//Add ID to the button
<button id = "toggle"></button>

//Outside the render method
   document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    If(e.target.style.display="none") {
        this.right.show()
    } Else {
        this.right.hide()
    }
```

})

Comment: I have already an state in my Menu would like to handle it over this and ur solution is  not that way how react expect it and it doesn't work.